# php swiftmailer sending mail with smtp transport timeout

Tags: php, email, smtp, centos, swiftmailer

I am trying to send mail via mandrill app using swift mailer. This is my code:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com',587);
$transport->setUsername($username);
$transport->setPassword($password);

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

    // Give the message a subject
    ->setSubject('New Order '.$reservationNumber)

    // Set the From address with an associative array
    ->setFrom(array('noreply@domain.com' => 'domain.com'))

    // Set the To addresses with an associative array
    ->setTo('test@domain.com')

    // Give it a body
    ->setBody($body,'text/html');

$mailer->send($message);
```

Credentials are 100% good. And i get timeout error: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mandrillapp.com [Connection timed out #110].

It looks like something is blocking connection. Maybe this is issue with server configurations? We are using WHM software on our centos server

Answer (score 2):

I've just been doing battle with exactly the same problem, but with smtp.gmail.com. It just would not work, even though the username/password etc were all correct.

In my case it seems that when PHP tries to connect to smtp.gmail.com, it gets the IPv6 address back - but their server seems to not be listening on that, since the Swiftmailer responds with the same timeout error you get.

But when I swapped in its IPv4 address (got by ping-ing it), it connected and sent the email just fine.

So find out what smtp.mandrillapp.com's IPv4 address is and try *that* IP in place of the hostname in the code. Does that connect and send now? It did for me.

It's not ideal coding in an IP address - given that they could change it at any minute - but at least you will get some emails sent

Answer (score 1):

Here it actually worked when I increased the timeout:

```
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail_server', 'mail_port', 'tls')
          ->setUsername('mail_user')
          ->setPassword('mail_pass')
          ->setTimeout(120)
        ;
```

The server I tried to access works with IPv6, maybe there is an issue with related to that.